# Heat equation on finite interval

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I want to show that
$$u(x,t)=\sum e^{-\lambda_n^2t}\langle f,u_n\rangle u_n(x)$$
where,
$$u_n(x)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{l}} \sin(\frac{n\pi x}{l})$$ and,
$$\lambda_n=\frac{n \pi c}{l}$$

satisfies

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = c^2 \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2},    0\leq x\leq l$$
$$u(x,0)=f(x)$$

I explicitly want to show that $u(x,t)$ satisfies the given differential equation. However, I am not sure how I can interchange derivative and summation.

Any help is appreciated.

Edit: $f \in L^2[0,l]$ such that $f(0)=f(l)=0$.

Comment: What do you know about $f(x)$? The ability to interchange a derivative and an infinite series depends on the convergence of the series, which in this case depends on the properties of $f$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f\in L^2$, the Fourier coefficients $\langle f,u_n\rangle$ are bounded, say $|\langle f,u_n\rangle|\le M$. Fix $t_0>0$. Then
$$
\bigl|e^{-\lambda_n^2t}\,\langle f,u_n\rangle\, u_n(x)\bigr|\le M\,\sqrt{\frac2l}\,e^{-\lambda_n^2t_0}.
$$
It follows that
$$
\sum e^{-\lambda_n^2t}\,\langle f,u_n\rangle\, u_n(x)
$$
converges uniformly on $[0,l]\times[t_0,\infty)$. The same can be said of the series obtained tagging derivatives inside the sum. This implies that the function defined by the series is $C\infty$ on $0,l=\times(0,\infty)$ and can be derived any number of times inside the sum.

Comment: When I take derivative with respect to $t$, I get $|e^{-\lambda_n^2t}\langle f,u_n\rangle u_n(x)| \leq M n^2 e^{-\lambda_n^2t_0}$, where I have absorbed other constants in $M$. Won't the $n^2$ create a problem?

Comment: No, because of the exponential term. Remember that $\lambda_n=Cn$, $C$ constant.